# GUI is Hanging When Serially Send Data

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyqt4

I am new to python and pyqt.I am created a gui using qt designer.In that gui when i clicked a push button a data will send serially.That time my Gui is hanged here is my code

interface.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'status.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from iF_UART import *

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,
        _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
         return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow, data_queue):
        self.bt = UartDriver()
        self.bt.init('COM5', 115200, 0)
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 140, 251, 91))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.action_func)
        self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 180, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.data_queue = data_queue

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton", None))



    def action_func(self):
        send_len = self.bt.write("hai")
```

app.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys
import interface
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep


qt_app = None


class Simulator(QtGui.QMainWindow, interface.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self,data_queue):
        super(Simulator, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self, data_queue)
        self.data_queue = data_queue
        self.count = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
# Function Main Start
def main():
    global qt_app
    qt_app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    data_queue = Queue()
    form = Simulator(data_queue)
    form.show()
    qt_app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

uart.py

```
import serial
import time
# time out 0.1 sec
TIME_OUT = 0.1
SER_MAX_DATA_SIZE = 1024

class UartDriver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flow_control = None
        self.serial_handle = None
        self.handle = None

    def init(self, com_port, baud_rate, flow_con=False, handle = ''):
        self.flow_control = flow_con
        self.handle = handle
        print "Opening %s at %d" % (com_port, baud_rate)
        try:
            if(flow_con):
                self.serial_handle = serial.Serial(com_port, baud_rate, rtscts=True)
            else:
                self.serial_handle = serial.Serial(com_port, baud_rate, rtscts=False, timeout=TIME_OUT)
        except:
            print "Could not open port"
        finally:
            pass

    def write(self, s_data):
        w_len = None
        try:
            if (self.serial_handle):
                if(self.flow_control):
                    pass
                else:
                    print "Send ",  (s_data)
                    w_len = self.serial_handle.write(bytearray(s_data+"\n"))
                    print "test"
            else:
                print "Invalid handle"
        except:
            self.serial_handle.close()
        finally:
            return(w_len)
```

In uart.py write takes place.Actually the writing is not completed because after the statement write i am just print a word test,but it cannot print on the console.Somebody please help me to avoid the hang of gui.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stack overflow. Take a look at the documentation, especially [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to give us a specific, minimal example that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by myself.In my uart class i opened a serial port at certain baudrate and a fixed read timeout.In my serial port opening i am added an extra argument that is write_timeout and it is set to zero

```
self.serial_handle = serial.Serial(com_port, baud_rate, rtscts=False, timeout=TIME_OUT, write_timeout=0)
```

Now my GUI is working fine.